# Parse not-well formed html on iphone (+XPath?)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xpath, html-parsing

I have to parse an HTML which is not well-formed.
I want to use XPath to retrieve some elements.
What could I use on iphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libxml2 and the function [PerformHTMLXPathQuery](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/XPathQuery.zip) by Marcus Zarra. See http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html